# Sleep the WebBrowser instance and not entire program while Scraping

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping

I'm writeing a batch program that scraps data from a website.

This is the code:

```
private async void buttonInfoJobs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string C_UrlTemplate= "https://www.mysite.it/{0}";

    var _searches = new List<Get_SiteSearchResult>();
    using (JobsDataContext db = new JobsDataContext())
    {
        _searches = db.Get_SiteSearch("JOBS").ToList();
        foreach (var s in _searches)
        {
            WebBrowserJobs wb1 = new WebBrowserJobs();
            Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(C_UrlTemplate,s.SkillTech));

            wb1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowserJobs_DocumentCompleted);
            wb1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowserJobs_Navigating);

            wb1.Url = uri;

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the website that I have to scrap is implementing Javascript in pages and to get the page, the webbrowser is reloaded different times.

This works perfectly if I ask just for an Url, the **DocumentCompleted** events is fired six times but finally I get the content required.

The problem comes when I have to ask for different urls in a loop: the website require captcha validation.

I can avoid this by implementing a delay of X seconds during the elaboration but I don't know how and were:

If I put System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000), all the execution is stoppend but I want to delay only the single task of the webbrowser...

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Since it's already `async`, why not `await Task.Delay(1000);`?

Comment: This helped me a lot, but I want to delay just the WebBrowser instance...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by delaying just the WebBrowser instance. If you don't want the WebBrowser to do anything then don't tell it to do anything, or just wait before telling it to do something.

Answer (score 1):

I've probably also answered your last question about the WebScraper, so I'm going to help you again ;)

You already have the `async` keyword in the function definition, so you can just use the following code:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

Comment: Hi Simon, yes It was me ;-)
I try your solution and let you know !

Comment: This helped me a lot, but I want to delay just the WebBrowser instance...